# Deploy scoped roles for web app in weblogic portal

Tags: deployment, weblogic, roles, visitor-pattern, entitlements

I want to ask if it is possible to create scoped roles for web app in my project and though deployment these roles to be seen in Administration Console?
For example I succeeded to see one security role that I created in WLP Console but I don't know what type of role was that and how can I would be able to set that role for some resources (book labels).

I used something like this:
TestRole1 in web.xml
TestRole1 in weblogic.xml

In this moment I create from WLP Administration Console, from Visitor Entitlements, new Visitor Role and after that I asign that role for my books in my desktop. I want all of these to be possible though deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use wlst to create those roles programatically as described here -

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/core.1111/e10043/managepols.htm#JISEC6781